# Blur image with ImageMagick and extent it

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, mogrify

I want to blur an image with transparent background using ImageMagick. I've trimmed this image to its content, so it doesn't have any surrounding whitespace/transparency.

The above part works fine, *but*:
When I blur the trimmed image, it will (obviously) overflow the boundaries. So the question is: **How can I blur a trimmed image, while extending its boundaries to the right size before?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the background with transparent pixels, blur and then re-trim:

```
convert original.png -background none -gravity center -extent 200x200% -blur ... -trim result.png
```

Comment: You may want to reduce the `200x200%` if you are only doing small blurs - that will speed things up. You may also want `+repage` before the output filename.